# How to pass json data through ajax in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular js and i wanted to pass one static json file through ajax and i am giving the codes below.How to Display the data of json file into the index file that i dont know. As i am new to angularjs please help me with these

Index.php

```
<body ng-app="Mymodule">
    <div ng-controller="recordscontroller">
        <table style="width:500px; border:solid 2px #CCC;">
            <thead>
                <tr style="text-align:left;">
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="emp in employee | orderBy : '-salary'">
                    <td>{{ emp.firstname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ emp.lastname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ emp.gender }}</td>
                    <td>{{ emp.salary | currency: 'Rs' }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> <br>
</body>
```

Script.js

```
var app = angular.module("Mymodule",[]);

    app.controller("recordscontroller", function($scope, $http){
        var url = "data/records.json";
        $http.get(url).success(function (response){
        $scope.employee = response;
        });
    });
```

records.json

```
[
    {
        "firstname":"Kishan",
        "lastname":"Dalsania",
        "gender":"Male",
        "salary":15000
    },
    {
        "firstname":"Dipesh",
        "lastname":"Mungara",
        "gender":"Male",
        "salary":20000
    },
    {
        "firstname":"Roshan",
        "lastname":"Trivedi",
        "gender":"Male",
        "salary":25000
    },
    {
        "firstname":"Jay",
        "lastname":"Dalsania",
        "gender":"Male",
        "salary":30000
    },
]
```

Comment: using objects we can send @Kishan Dalsania

Comment: How? Can you help me out by showing the code? just as an example.

Comment: ignore the syntax error in your json? pre-last line `},` -> `}`

Comment: TypeError: dbg is undefined I am getting these type of error in console

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/qwd0y1pa/ wihout request, there is no error, except your syntax in your json file -- btw that seems not to cause the problem, i added the , too

Comment: Thanks Mephiztopheles I think you are right

Comment: was it the `,`? :D

Comment: Yeaah actually in console i am able to find whole data of json the problem is that with requesting it is not displaying in index.php
No by removing , yet not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid JSON.

If you check this version
https://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/qwd0y1pa
and this
https://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/qwd0y1pa/1/
`JSON.parse('[{"firstname":"Kishan", "lastname":"Dalsania","gender":"Male","salary":15000},{ "firstname":"Dipesh", "lastname":"Mungara", "gender":"Male","salary":20000},{ "firstname":"Roshan", "lastname":"Trivedi", "gender":"Male", "salary":25000 }, {  "firstname":"Jay",  "lastname":"Dalsania", "gender":"Male", "salary":30000},]')`

you will see

Comment: Ok it worked. Thanks for help :)
Is there any problem with request type? Without request it is working perfectly.

Comment: no, normally the xhtmlrequest detects which content-type the response is. javascript can parse the incorrect `,` but JSON doesn't